# HBase connector - Thrift or REST

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

There seem to be at least 2 ways to connect to HBase from external application, with language other then Java (i.e. Python):

1. HBase Thrift API
2. HBase Stargate (REST API)

Does anyone know which one should be used in which circumstances?
I.e. what are their main differences, and pros/cons?

Answer (score 2):

Thrift is generally faster because the data being exchanged is smaller.  Stargate offers a web service which is an integration method that is widely supported, which is a concern when you are working with commercial products with limited integration possibilities.

In a closed environment where everything is controlled, I would prefer Thrift.  If I'm exposing data to external teams or systems I would prefer Stargate.